# Would reflection be the best method of searching for a value of a specific property in a list of Objects?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a Class with the following:

```
public class TestClass {
    string Account1 {get;set;}
    string Account2 {get;set;}
    string Account3 {get;set;}
}
```

What I would like is to be able to have a method that is similar to the following:

```
public TestClass[] GetTestClass(string value, string AccountName)
```

where i can pass in a value say "John" and the AccountName would be "Account1"

and it will go through a list of TestClass and return an array or list of TestClass objects where there exists a value "John" in the Property "Account1"

Is there a better method of doing this or any thoughts would help.

Note: This is a model based of a SQL Table

Comment: Yes you can use the reflectionto get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to get what you want, Your method will look like this,

```
public List<TestClass> GetTestClass(string value, string AccountName)
{
     foreach(TestClass test in yourListOfTestClass)
       {
         if (test.GetType().GetProperty(AccountName).GetValue(test, null).Equals(value))
             listToReturn.Add(test);
       }
    return listToReturn
 }
```

**Note** - Code is not tested. Might have synatx error.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better method of doing this or any thoughts would help.

You can use List of strings instead of multiple string variables  as you are returning array from GetTestClass. It will keep it simple as well.

```
public class TestClass 
{
    List<string> Accounts = new List<string>();   
}
```

Now you will only pass the value to method. Using the `LinQ` will filter out the desired string list using `Where`.

```
public List<string> GetTestClass(string value)
{
     return Accounts.Where(account => account == value).ToList();
}
```

**Edit** The OP want two things AccountName and the Name, this would require to have a account class instead of string.

```
class Account
{
    string AccountName { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass 
{
    List<Account> Accounts = new List<Account>();   
}


public Account GetTestClass(Account account)
{
     return Accounts.Where(account => a.AccountName == account.AccountName && a.Name == account.Name).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: That will compare *all* items in the list to the string, not a specific item.

Comment: I need to compare for example Account1 only to "John". If Account2 has John, I need it to be ignored

Comment: Keep in mind that the questioner probably has no means to change the model. So suggesting other options might be misleading.

Comment: @Rouby, In OP I think he asked for alternative, "Is there a better method of doing this or any thoughts would help."

Comment: Yes I know, but later he edited it and added "Note: This is a model based of a SQL Table" which suggests to me that he might not be able to make modelchanges.

Answer (score 1):

You can send in a method for accessing the property instead of the property name:

```
public TestClass[] GetTestClass(string value, Func<TestClass, string> getAccountName) {
  return accounts.Where(x => getAccountName(x) == value).ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

```
TestClass[] johnsAccounts = GetTestClass("John", a => a.Account1);
```

Or simply use it directly:

```
TestClass[] johnsAccounts = accounts.Where(a => a.Account1 == "John").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

Take a look into [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173183.aspx). This should get you started.

Example:

```
public TestClass[] GetTestClass(string value, string AccountName)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty(AccountName);
    var list = new List<TestClass>();
    foreach(var tc in [YOUR_OBJECTS])
    {
        if(propertyInfo.GetValue(tc, null) == value)
        {
            list.add(tc);
        }
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achieve that using [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). Though, I don't think I would do that this way, since there are other ways to implement what you want differently.

A better way in my opinion would be to create a type-safe enum that would do that. In the members of the type-safe enum, you could specify an action that would run against a 'TestClass' object.

You would be able to call 'GetTestClass' in this way:

```
var accounts1 = GetTestClass(testClassesCollection, "john", TestProperties.Account1);
var accounts2 = GetTestClass(testClassesCollection, "john", TestProperties.Account2);
var accounts3 = GetTestClass(testClassesCollection, "john", TestProperties.Account3);
```

Where 'testClassesColleciton' is the collection of 'TestClass' that you have. You could remove this argument if the method is an object member.

The type-safe enum is implemented this way:

```
public sealed class TestProperties
{
     public static readonly TestProperties Account1 = new TestProperties((t, name) => t.Account1 == name);
     public static readonly TestProperties Account2 = new TestProperties((t, name) => t.Account2 == name);
     public static readonly TestProperties Account3 = new TestProperties((t, name) => t.Account3 == name);

    private Func<TestClass, string, bool> _checkFunc;

    private TestProperties(Func<TestClass, string, bool> func)
    {
        _checkFunc = func;  
    }

    public bool IsApplicable(TestClass test, string name)
    {
        return _checkFunc(test, name);  
    }
}
```

Then, you can implement the GetTestClass this way:

```
public TestClass[] GetTestClass(IEnumerable<TestClass> testClasses, string value, TestProperties property)
{
        return testClasses.Where( t => property.IsApplicable(t)).ToArray();
}
```

I wouldn't use reflection because of it's performance overhead and it's maintenance danger. With a plain simple reflection, we will pass the property's name as a string parameter. What would happen if somebody has changed the property's name in the class? Even with Visual Studio refactoring (ctrl + R, R), the string parameter value will not be updated. Since the code will compile normally, the bug will be discovered only at run-time.

I agree with @Rouby that a plain simple reflection will be faster to develop than the type-safe enum way that I have suggested. Though, personally, I don't think that it will be that much cheaper (development-cost wise) and I also think that the potentially dangerous scenario that I talked about earlier (regarding refactoring) would have a bigger development-cost penalty, specially, when it is a legacy/old code.

Comment: I think this method is too much overhead. Why wouldnt you use reflection? Its simpler and less code to write. If speed is a concern he should do this check on the database anyway.

Comment: @Rouby Thanks for the correction :) I wouldn't use reflection because it's hacky, dangerous, and potentially has Performance penalty. I usually try not to use reflection when there are other options that aren't too much difficult to implement.

Comment: I think your method would impact development-speed.. and sometimes thats an even higher cost. Since the question states that this is something coming from a database, speed is not likely to be a concern (he could do this search on the database if he needed the speed). Also I dont think that there are any dangers here.

Comment: @Rouby I think that it would be a balance between development speed and code maintenance. Even though the type-safe enum has a higher development-speed cost, I don't think it will make that much of a difference. At the other hand, using plain simple reflection is not as simple to read (specially for junior developers).

Comment: @Rouby Also, I think reflection would be dangerous because it uses the property's name. What would happen if somebody would change the property's name? The program will compile, but won't work as expected. I think that this would have a much higher speed-development cost (debugging, specially if it is a legacy/old code).

Comment: I disagree with that, but comments are not for lengthy discussions. Please add your reasons why you dont recommend reflection to your answer so readers of that answer can make their own decisions based on that.

Comment: @Rouby I agree about the lengthy discussions. Thanks for the remarks, I have edited my post to include the reasons.